# Win32 detect if window is maximized/docked to half screen (Win-key + Left/Right)

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a classic Win32-API (C++) application and need to detect if the window is docked to the left/right half of the screen.

Background of the question is that the window only sizes in grid steps, let's say 32 pixel.  In full screen the program detects that state, allow size to match the full screen and pad the excess space.  With Windows 8 and later I would like to do the same instead of currently leaving borders (because the size snaps to a multiple of 32 pixel).

Comment: A window does not have a special state when it is "docked" like this.  The shell simply provides the user with a shortcut to move the window there, no different from moving it there with the mouse.  Detect it with GetWindowRect and GetMonitorInfo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what IInspectable has already mentioned, there is another way to determine this information and act accordingly.

1. Wait for a [`WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632652.aspx) message and read its `x`, `y`, `cx`, and `cy` values from the [`WINDOWPOS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632612.aspx) pointer stored in `lParam`.
2. Get a handle to the current monitor on which the window is placed by calling [`MonitorFromWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dd145064.aspx).
3. Create a [`MONITORINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dd145065.aspx) variable and set its `cbSize` field to `sizeof(MONITORINFO)`.
4. Use the monitor handle and the address of your `MONITORINFO` variable to call [`GetMonitorInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dd144901.aspx).
5. Read the `rcWork` value from your `MONITORINFO` variable.

   - `rcWork.top == WINDOWPOS.y && rcWork.bottom == (WINDOWPOS.y + WINDOWPOS.cx) && rcWork.left == WINDOWPOS.x` - the window is "docked" to the left
   - `rcWork.top == WINDOWPOS.y && rcWork.bottom == (WINDOWPOS.y + WINDOWPOS.cx)  && rcwork.right == (WINDOWPOS.x + WINDOWPOS.cx)` - the window is "docked" to the right
   - `rcWork.top == WINDOWPOS.y && rcWork.left == WINDOWPOS.x && rcWork.right == (WINDOWPOS.x + WINDOWPOS.cx)` - the window is "docked" to the top
   - `rcWork.top == (WINDOWPOS.y + WINDOWPOS.cy) && rcWork.left == WINDOWPOS.x && rcWork.right == (WINDOWPOS.x + WINDOWPOS.cx)` - the window is "docked" to the bottom

You say you already have logic to determine if the window is fullscreen (do you mean fullscreen or maximized?), but effective maximization can be determined if `left == x && top == y && right == x + cx && bottom == y + cy`.

[Here is an MSDN example of something similar.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dd162826.aspx)

Note that it may be more desirable to cache the `MONITORINFO` values so you don't need to call it every time the window is repositioned.

---

If you only want this to apply when a user does NOT manually resize the window, here is a *contrived* example of a possible way to do so:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK windowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
  static bool userSizing = false;

  switch (msg)
  {
  // could also catch WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE here, but this will trigger on 
  // moves as well as sizes
  case WM_SIZING:
    userSizing = true;
    break;

  case WM_EXITSIZEMOVE:
    userSizing = false;
    break;

  case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED:
    if (userSizing)
    {
      break;
    }

    // do logic to check to see if the window is sized in a "docked"
    // manner here
    break;

  // handle other window messages ...

  }
}
```

Comment: This algorithm cannot distinguish between a window being docked using Aero Snap, and a window that happens to be sized and positioned identically, but done so manually by a user. Handling `WM_SIZING` is essential in differentiating between the user resizing a window, and the system doing it.

Comment: @IInspectable: you're absolutely correct. I wrote this answer with the idea that it doesn't really matter if the user resizes the window to exact "docking" dimensions or if Aero Snap is used as it is effectively identical, but the method of resizing may actually matter for usability purposes. I'll add another suggestion regarding this.

Comment: `WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE` is sent to a window, when the user starts a move operation as well, which could essentially result in docking a window. That would result in a false negative.

Comment: Actually, the situation is worse. `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` is sent throughout sizing and moving operations. The proposed implementation produces false negatives exclusively. I haven't tried it, but I believe a reliable implementation would set the flag in `WM_SIZING` and reset it during `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE`. A corner case would be when resizing the undocked edge of a docked window. I'm not even sure, what should happen in that case.

Comment: I'm currently not in a position to test it, but yes, I forgot `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` is called *during* moves/sizes - that's how WinForms handles live control layouts. The issue is that I don't know if `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE` is sent before or after `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` without testing it out -- which I can't do for another few hours.

Comment: I did cursory testing, and it seems that `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE` consistently follows the final `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`, although the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632623.aspx) is somewhat fuzzy on the subject: *"Sent one time to a window, after it has exited the moving or sizing modal loop."* That could really mean anything; the internals of the modal loop are - to my knowledge - not documented.

Comment: Sorry for taking to long to come back, I had seen the initial comment and thought that was that.
Thanks for the elaborate sample and the detailed discussion afterwards.  I'm interested in a practical solution, so if a user accidentally exactly hits half-pane while sizing I can live with that.

Answer (score 6):

With the function `GetWindowPlacement()` you can retrieve the normal window rectangle, using the member `rcNormalPosition` of `WINDOWPLACEMENT`. Then compare the normal rectangle to the actual window rectangle. If they don't match the window is most likely in a docked state.

Example:

```
bool IsDockedToMonitor(HWND hWnd)
{
    WINDOWPLACEMENT placement = {sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT)};
    GetWindowPlacement(hWnd, &placement);
    RECT rc;
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rc);

    return placement.showCmd == SW_SHOWNORMAL
        && (rc.left != placement.rcNormalPosition.left ||
            rc.top != placement.rcNormalPosition.top ||
            rc.right != placement.rcNormalPosition.right ||
            rc.bottom != placement.rcNormalPosition.bottom);
}
```

Note that this solution is not reliable 100% of the time.  There is a slim chance that the normal rectangle and current window rectangle could match even when the window is docked to the side of the monitor.

Comment: This may be unreliable since GetWindowPlacement uses workspace coordinates while GetWindowRect uses screen coordinates (see [WINDOWPLACEMENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-windowplacement)).  For instance, I believe the coordinates will not match when there is a bar docked to the top or left side of the screen.  However, it has been years since I have tested this.

Answer (score 4):

The *Aero Snap* feature is built into the Shell, not the window manager. As such, there is no particular window style or flag that indicates the docked state. The Shell simply repositions windows in response to certain actions (and internally records the state). It does so in a way that is indistinguishable from manually repositioning a window with the mouse or keyboard.

You cannot reliably determine, whether a window is docked to the left or right of the screen. There is no particular message sent by the Shell, nor is a window's size and position relative to the working area a sufficient property.

What you are trying to accomplish isn't possible. You will have to implement a solution, that doesn't require the information that isn't available. One such implementation would be to always use padding for window sizes, that don't allow the entire client area to be used. Another solution would be to implement the opposite: Allow window resizing to any size, unless you know the user is manually resizing the window. You can determine the latter by handling the [WM_SIZING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632647.aspx) message.