# How do you know when the docking state of a toolbar has changed

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc

Someone asked a similar question @ [Detecting when a CControlBar's docking state has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523942/detecting-when-a-ccontrolbars-docking-state-has-changed/58459824), but the answer is written from the standpoint of the control.  I want to know when the docking state changes from CFrameWnd, because I have a window filling up the client area that needs to be repositioned whenever the docking state changes.  My current WM_SIZE code works, but not if a toolbar is docked or undocked.

Comment: You may need to calculate the window size. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47888651/win32-detect-if-window-is-maximized-docked-to-half-screen-win-key-left-right

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `AdjustDockingLayout` function of `CFrameWndEx`.
It will be called every time docking layout is changed.

[MSDN info:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmdiframewndex-class?view=vs-2019#adjustdockinglayout)

Note:
During the creation of the Docking windows, there are multiple calls to this function (you might want to ignore them).

```
void CMainFrame::AdjustDockingLayout(HDWP hdwp)
{
    CMDIFrameWndEx::AdjustDockingLayout(hdwp);

    // do some calulations
}
```